# "Wrong Architecture" when installing markdown parsers via npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.4. When I try to install `robotskirt` or `node-discount`, I get wrong architecture errors. Example:

```
[1/2] cxx: src/markdown.cc -> build/Release/src/markdown_1.o
[2/2] cxx_link: build/Release/src/markdown_1.o -> build/Release/markdown.node
ld: warning: ignoring file ./libmarkdown.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/jong/node_modules/discount/build'
'build' finished successfully (2.639s)
discount@0.2.3 node_modules/discount
```

And robotskirt:

```
[1/7] cc: src/markdown.c -> build/Release/src/markdown_1.o
[2/7] cc: src/array.c -> build/Release/src/array_1.o
[3/7] cc: src/buffer.c -> build/Release/src/buffer_1.o
[4/7] cc: src/html.c -> build/Release/src/html_1.o
[5/7] cxx: src/robotskirt.cc -> build/Release/src/robotskirt_2.o
[6/7] cxx_link: build/Release/src/robotskirt_2.o build/Release/src/markdown_1.o build/Release/src/array_1.o build/Release/src/buffer_1.o build/Release/src/html_1.o -> build/Release/robotskirt.node
[7/7] cc_link: build/Release/src/markdown_1.o build/Release/src/array_1.o build/Release/src/buffer_1.o build/Release/src/html_1.o -> build/Release/libsundown.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/markdown_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/array_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/buffer_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/html_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/markdown_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/array_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/buffer_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: ignoring file Release/src/html_1.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/jong/node_modules/robotskirt/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.406s)
robotskirt@0.2.5 node_modules/robotskirt
```

It looks like a C compiler issue to me, but I know nothing about that. Tickets I've opened: https://github.com/benmills/robotskirt/issues/20#issuecomment-6794474, https://github.com/visionmedia/node-discount/issues/20.

Anyone know how I can fix this, or how I can solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install Node? Which version is it? If I were you, I would do a complete uninstall and install 0.8 from official pkg or compiling from source. It looks like your libraries are completely messed up. If you installed Node compiling from source, it has uninstall target in `Makefile` so you can do `make uninstall` to easily uninstall it from your system.

Comment: v0.8 by binary from nodejs.org. i already tried reinstalling but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. I was not correct, obviously. Please make sure that your default compiler is gcc. If you install and use gcc as compiler, I believe this will be solved.

Comment: How do I check if it is? if I do `gcc -v` I get `4.2.1`. During the build, I see the following: `Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++`

Comment: Do you have Xcode? I am sorry that I do not have a access to any OS X machine and have no experience at it; but as I remember from many bug reports and complaints about these, Xcode was always mentioned. Update Xcode to its latest version or install if you don't have it. Then please give building Node from source on your machine a try. It is not difficult at all. `./configure && make` install that is all. To use gcc instead of g++ set CC environment variable to gcc on your system, like `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2.1`

Comment: yup, I updated to the latest version when I got this problem, and it didn't help. Let me try that what you just suggested in a sec.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: If you can install other modules, these are probably problems with these specific modules instead of node or npm. I have just tried installing them on Debian64 via `npm install` and discount did not work for me either, although the error message is different. If you can install other modules without problems, then the best thing to do at this point is to send bug reports for these two modules.

Comment: yup, did that. they don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more than one C compiler on your path, or a C compiler and a linker that don't match (in particular, one is for x86 and one is x64). Use "which -a gcc" and "which -a ld" to find out where the compiler and linker are being run from. If those commands output more than one thing, you'll want to edit the PATH environment to variable exclude one of those directories and control which version runs.

Comment: `which -a gcc`: `/usr/bin/gcc`, `which -a ld`: `/usr/bin/ld`. I guess not.